# Java AWT - The rectangle2d object's width differs in Java8 vs Java11

Tags: java, java-8, awt, java-11

One of my projects is to migrate from Java8 to Java11. I have a TextLayout object. I am trying to get a Rectangle2D object using **textLayout.getBounds()**.

One strange thing I observe is that the width of the Rectangle2D object is different in Java11 from that of Java8. How is this possible?

My Code:

```
package sample;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.TextLayout;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class Main extends Frame {
    public Main() {
        super("Java 2D Example01");
        setSize(400, 300);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        FontRenderContext frc = ((Graphics2D) g).getFontRenderContext();
        Font f = new Font("Times", Font.BOLD, 30);

        TextLayout tl = new TextLayout("10x25in-Diagram1", f, frc);
        Rectangle2D rectangleForAllText = tl.getBounds();
        System.out.println(rectangleForAllText);


 //java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=2.375,y=-21.5625,w=250.4375,h=27.875]

//java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=2.375,y=-21.5625,w=253.43736,h=27.875]
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Main();

    }
}
```

> As you can see in the two comments: The rectangleForAllText object in
>   Java8: 
>   **java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=2.375,y=-21.5625,w=250.4375,h=27.875]**
>
> The same object in Java11:
>   **java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=2.375,y=-21.5625,w=253.43736,h=27.875]**

Can someone please tell me why this is the case? Any fix/suggestions would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. (upvoted)

Comment: 1) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing. 2) *"Can someone please tell me why this is the case?"* It might be that between Java 8 and 11, the JRE tweaked how it renders fonts, or which font it uses by default.. which reminds me. 3) *`Font f = new Font("Times", Font.BOLD, 30);`* Don't guess font names. Here there is a `Times New Roman` font, but when I print out `f` I get `java.awt.Font[family=Dialog,name=Times,style=bold,size=30]`.

Comment: .. 4) BTW `Main` is a poor class name. I usually try to run code that people post, but many ppl use the general names like `Main` or `Test`. In order to run that code, I'd either need to create a new package, or delete previous examples that used the same name. Many times, I could not be bothered doing that. A specific name like `TestFontBoxSize` is more unique and descriptive.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I get it about the class name. Wanted to run a quick sample program... Coming to your point #1, It is an org decision to stick with AWT. Can't really do much about that  :( . Thanks for your comments. Will look into this further.

Comment: Okay, the variation in the width is inconsistent with different fonts. I used Tahoma,plain,12 now and in java11 the width is relatively less compared to java8.

    **Java8**:
`//java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=1.328125,y=-8.90625,w=94.25,h=11.390625]`
        
    **Java11**:
 `//java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=1.325,y=-8.9125,w=91.44992,h=11.387501]`

Comment: The font rendering engine has changed.